# JPA MSSQL - saving data with Chinese characters - saved as?

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using MSSQL and I'm facing the same issue with JPA. While saving Chinese characters, all are being written as `???`. On the other forum, someone suggested adding an `N` prefix in front of insert query. However, I'm using JPA's save method. How can I add this prefix `N` while saving?

Comment: JPA doesnt have a "save" method

Comment: Can you provide mssql configuration and table structure for affected tables

Comment: I'm using this class JpaRepository (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository) which does have save method accepting corresponding entity object for the table. So I'm unable to append 'N' prefix in front of the query.

Comment: Thanks for reply. with respect to MSSQL configuration,  Server Collation is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Language is set to English (United States).  the fields (columns) that I'm writing are declared as nvarchar(4000). Is that something useful? otherwise let me know.

Comment: So you aren't using the JPA API, and are instead using Spring Data JPA

Comment: that is correct. is there a way to solve this? any work around?

Comment: anyone have an idea on this how to get data saved with MSSQL using Spring JPA?